# How to batch process contents of a database table?

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to do the following:

- Connect to a Postgres database and select the contents of a particular table 2 rows at a time
- Take the 2 rows, convert them to CSV strings and send that string over the wire to a RESTful API endpoint

The problem I am having is that in order to process the ResultSet and convert it into a CSV String, I need to call `rs.next()` but in doing that, I am pulling the next 'batch' from the database. Here's the code I have so far:

```
public void load() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = connectToDB();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        st.setFetchSize(2);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM friends");
        String csv = resultSetToCSV(rs);
        System.out.println("CSV output is: " + csv);

        rs.close();
        st.close();
    }

    private static String resultSetToCSV(ResultSet rs) throws Exception {
        int colCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                result.append("\"").append(rs.getString(i + 1)).append('"');
            }
            result.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

How can I get this to work so that each "batch" of 2 rows is processed and converted to a CSV string? I want to do this because I am going to be running this on a very large table which won't fit into memory (I am just testing it out with a batch size of 2).

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean to do. The fetch size tells JDBC how many rows to fetch if `rs.next()` is called and no more rows are in the fetched buffer. But if it's going to be a large table, then the problem is going to be on the CSV side which is going to grow large.

Comment: Basically I only want to read 2 rows at a time from the database, so that only 2 rows are in memory at any one time. The CSV won't grow large because the CSV will be sent off to an HTTP endpoint and then thrown away. Essentially I want to 'stream' from the database into an external HTTP service.

Comment: Then all you need to do is to write the CSV to your output stream after each read. You don't need to do anything in the code after you told it to fetch only two rows at a time.

Comment: But rs.next() returns a single row at a time from the ResultSet, so how can I package up all the rows in the batch without pulling the next batch of 2 records through?

Comment: It's going to give you each row, and you'll package it to your CSV, and internally it will be fetching two rows each time, so you won't have all the rows in memory, only the current two. I'm not really sure what's bothering you about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the fetch size with ResultSet.setFetchSize(int) but generally you should not concern yourself with the entire table fitting in memory and let the driver do the job.